# 'firebase' is not recognized as an internal command or external, an executable program or a batch file

Tags: firebase-cli

i'm  trying  to  login in  firebase but i  can't  , i added  the  path in the environement  and  trying  this  solution  but still not  working ,  this is my  code  here in cmd  ,  any  help plz ?

```
C:\Users\MAISON INFO>cd mystore



C:\Users\MAISON INFO\mystore>code .

C:\Users\MAISON INFO\mystore>firebase login
'firebase' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

C:\Users\MAISON INFO\mystore>cd /

C:\>cd Users\MAISON INFO\AppData\Roaming\npm

C:\Users\MAISON INFO\AppData\Roaming\npm>firebase login
'firebase' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

C:\Users\MAISON INFO\AppData\Roaming\npm>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use the Firebase CLI, you need to install it first. The error you are receiving is a result of not having installed the CLI first.

Seeing your command prompt, you seem to be on Windows. There are two methods to install the Firebase CLI on Windows: using a standalone binary (using a separate shell) or using npm.

The standalone binary can be installed from the following link: https://firebase.tools/bin/win/instant/latest
After opening the binary, you will be able to use `firebase login` or any other firebase command in the shell it opens.

However, if you wish to use the Firebase CLI on the command prompt as you are showing you intend to, you can use the following command:
`npm install -g firebase-tools`. This will require having Node v10.13.0 or later.

If you are on a different operating system, or want to learn more about the Firebase CLI as well as its installation, here is some good documentation you may wish to read: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli

Comment: i already installed it and  still not  workinf  , it's  really  complicated :/

Comment: It may be that your node variables aren't being added to path properly, have you installed anything else globally with npm/node?

Comment: it's worked  thank you , i just  installed firebase

Comment: Glad I could help!